# Beamer org-mode: pause between blocks, overlays, uncover blocks

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode, beamer

I just try to make two blocks in the same frame to be displayed one at a time, same frame, but beamer should generate 2 slides.
I cannot figure out how. The documentation at [orgmode](http://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/beamer/tutorial.html) is not enough for me.

I would be very grateful to understand how to pause a slide at some point, same as with `...` in Pandoc if possible. I am not sure if this is possible at all in org mode with beamer.

My example below:

I have something like this and I want each of the cols displayed at one time. My settings are `H:3` for the frame level.

```
*** Continuous integration with Jenkins
  :PROPERTIES:
  :BEAMER_env: theorem
  :END:
**** Jenkins
    :PROPERTIES:
    :BEAMER_col: 0.65
    :END:
     [[./jenkins-dashboard.png]]
**** Jenkins
    :PROPERTIES:
    :BEAMER_col: 0.35
    :END:
     #+ATTR_BEAMER: :overlay +-
     - contiuosly building
     - latest failure
     - latest success
     - build durations
```

The example at "3.4 Using Babel" from http://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/beamer/tutorial.html adjusted to my needs (changed frame level) seems not to work either.

Comment: Stack Overflow is probably not the best place for this self-answered question. If you think it contains enough merit you might want to transfer it to http://tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `#+BEAMER: \pause` anywhere in a slide will pause the slide. That worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question and found a nice solution with `:BEAMER_act: <+->`
The thing inside `< >` follows exactly beamer overlay syntax.

This works on `Emacs 24.5.1 (Org mode 8.3.4)`